# Integrate user's Google Calendar to Angular application

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have an application with firebase auth and google auth. I need to integrate google calendar, like this.
User login and somehow i need to get his own calendar and integrate it to the special page, so each user on this page will see his own google calendar and can add reminders, somehow integrate push notifications from calendar and show at the application.
I tried to find how to do it, but unfortunately...
Maybe someone knows hot to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a library that may help: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Otherwise you can try to figure out how to authenticate your app without a library: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth and just use the `HttpClient` service to make requests to the api. In angular you generally wrap http requests in another service.

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GoogleCalendarService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3';

  getSomething(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/pathToRequest');
  }
}
```

All requests you can make are located here:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference

If you want a ready to go calendar component, there are a few but they aren't free:

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/Widgetsgallery/Demo/Scheduler/GoogleCalendarIntegration/Angular/Light/

https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/eventcalendar/load-events-from-google-calendar

That being said, you can probably find a free calendar component and just populate it using the api.